# split.bat - how to save list1,list2 and not list1-part1,list-part2?

Tags: batch-file

This is split.bat script for Windows. My question is how do I save list1, list2 and not

```
list1-part1
list-part2
list-part3
```

This is the script I found and tried. Can anybody modify it?

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set file=%1
set limit=%2
set lineCounter=1
set filenameCounter=1

set name=
set extension=
for %%a in (%file%) do (
    set "name=%%~na"
    set "extension=%%~xa"
)

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%file%) do (
    set splitFile=!name!-part!filenameCounter!!extension!
    if !lineCounter! gtr !limit! (
        set /a filenameCounter=!filenameCounter! + 1
        set lineCounter=1
        echo Created !splitFile!.
    )
    echo %%a>> !splitFile!

    set /a lineCounter=!lineCounter! + 1

  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line `set splitFile=!name!-part!filenameCounter!!extension!`

to this `set splitFile=!name!!filenameCounter!!extension!`

Comment: Thanks a lot is working saving to Dos\Windows can u do something to save it to Unix ? thanks a lot

Comment: @MunteanCosmin If your problem is solved, you should in this case mark this answer as accepted ==>  http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Hackoo can u help me now with a script to Join files? file1 file2 file3 file 4 etc... thanks

Comment: @MunteanCosmin What did you mean by join files ? Please post another question in new section and explain more your aim !

Comment: this site do not allowed me to make another post, so i must wait...ufff, how long?

Comment: @MunteanCosmin Mark this answer as accepted and try again to post another question